# How to turn Certificate Request into certificate

Tags: iis-7, ssl, certificate-authority

We have set up a Certificate Authority,

We have now created a certificate request.

How do we turn this certificate request into an actual certificate at the authority?

Answer (score 0):

Very much depends on the software you use to maintain the Certificate Authority. If you use OpenSSL there are helper scripts called CA.pl or CA.sh. I am also a huge fan of "easy-rsa" (google for it).

Comment: We use Windows server 2008 to maintain the authority. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenSSL, see http://novosial.org/openssl/ca/ You'll probably want to download and inspect the Makefile.

OpenSSL.org don't have a CA tutorial that I can find.

If IIS7 includes some CA certificate-signing options, you should probably ignore this answer. Although certificates produced and certified using OpenSSL should work just as well.

Aha! http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753127(WS.10).aspx